# How to add a CSS attribute to Image

Tags: media

i need to add class to image.

so i have 3 column in my site.

each column have block for news, i need to add class for each images.

first class is `.imgsmall {width:355px; height:125px;}`

second class is `.imgmid {width:455px; height:225px;}`

third class is `.imgbig {width:455px; height:325px;}`

how can add this class for image what i need

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure the approach you are taking is wrong, since you can use block's classes to address the images properly, like: block-12 img or something like that, also you can use a module called block class to ease the pain for styling

Comment: if you don't take @Sohail's advice above, how are these images created in the first place? if they are created via https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_image/7 the how of adding a class should be self evident.